# C# Failing To Import All of the Cells from an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, import-from-excel

I am using some legacy code to return an Excel worksheet as a Dataset.  However, when I iterate over the resulting data set it seems that not all of the cells are there.  The Excel sheet that is being read has some merged cells and I am wondering if that is the problem.  Here is the code:

```
private DataSet Get_Spreadsheet_Data(string strFileName, string strSheetName)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + strFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
    try
    {
        objConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + strSheetName + "$]", objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
        objAdapter1.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //litOutput.Text = "<span style=\"color:red;\">Exception Occurred pulling data from the spreadsheet.</span><br>Details: " + Ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        objConn.Close();
        objConn.Dispose();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Is this code malfunctioning?  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + strFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```

needed to read:

```
string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + strFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;";
```

and that did the trick!

Comment: Quotes are not right in the code shown. The `"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"` is the value for the `Extended Properties`, and needs to be wrapped in quotes (inside the string).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the same code with an Excel file that doesn't have the merged files?
That is the first thing I would try if I would wonder if merged cells can cause problems filling your dataset...

Edit for clarification:
For debugging purposes: use the same Excel file, only make sure you undo the merging of the cells. 
Even better is to start with an excel file with 3 rows and 3 columns:

Row one: Cell A1 with value 'Foo; Cell B1 'Bar', C1 banana.
Row two: Cell A2 Foo1 B2 Bar1 <-- merge those two cells. C2 = Apple.
Row three: Cell A3 with value 'Foo2; Cell B3 'Bar2'  C3 Orange <-- to check if the next line is read well after using merged cells...